# EOSID - Adhere to at or soon after V1?

Tags: takeoff, boeing-737, obstacle-clearance

Most airports have an Engine Out Standard Instrument Departure (EOSID) statement similar to this on their charts:

> For EOSIDs, the take-off performance for "ABC Airport" is based on the following Engine Failure Procedure and routes. They must be adhered to, at or soon after V1. Maintain between 15-25 bank angle and a maximum of 190kts IAS during turns.

My question is:

**Is the V1 catered for balanced or unbalanced field length, and how does it affect obstacle clearance?**

Comment: Care to define "EOSID" for those not familiar? (Some people aren't pilots and are just here to learn.) Also, I presume "ABC Airport" is a generic place. Please improve the formatting of your opening paragraph to make it more readable, you can quote a block of text using the `>` character at the beginning of a line of quoted text, or put it in quotes `""` or something to help improve readability.

Comment: Thank you FreeMan! I will update the question with your recommendations!

Comment: Thanks. I tweaked the formatting a bit to try to make it a bit smoother

Answer (score 2):

V1 should be calculated based on the actual conditions, so if you have an unbalanced field available, that's what it should be calculated from.

The V1 speed *itself* has zero effect on obstacle clearance. In most cases, V1 can be selected within a range between the lowest accelerate-go speed and the highest accelerate-stop speed, and that selection in & of itself won't change how much you clear any obstacles in a given scenario, unless the V1 was high enough to keep you on the ground.

Obstacle clearance is affected by things like rotation point and speed, climb speed, and thrust available. If the choice of V1 has effects on these, then there may be secondary effects, such as those coming from ruling out cases with a very late & very slow rotation (i.e. a high V1 means that early engine failures result in an abort rather than a continued takeoff).

A high V1 means that the worst case *that you have to consider* starts with more energy, having had all engines working for longer during the takeoff roll. But, if the engine were to fail at any point other than that worst case, how far past V1 you are makes no difference.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Ralph J! So if the choice of V1 has no effect on obstacle clearance, since the OPT (on-board performance tool) would have catered for it... would there be any benefit in delaying my rotation past Vr (rotate speed) during an engine out? I am thinking no, because doing that will affect my ability to achieve 35ft above the end of runway.

Comment: Well... I'm not going to advise anybody to operate outside of their written procedures, so this isn't a recommendation for that.  There can be advantages to a later, faster rotation speed, ***if*** the available runway permits. The computed performance data is based on rotating at Vr in all cases (unless they give you something else, like SETOS -- the "Single Engine Take Off Speed", which the T-38 had).  If you're taking off from a 12,000' runway in something reasonably light, delaying rotation by a few knots probably doesn't reduce your runway end height below 35', but without data...

Comment: ... without data specific to your conditions & runway, you don't really know how close you are to a performance limit, and if that extra 10 knots will cause a problem somewhere else.  There could be cases where a published SETOS well above Vr might do good things for your climb performance later, but if you don't have that data, I wouldn't go making it up on the fly.  (That said, rotation rates engine-out are often a bit slower than normal, and that's often written in the procedures... which has a bit of the same effects as an increased Vr.)